# Error when executing Grails application in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: grails, spring-tool-suite

I get the following error when executing my Grails application in Spring Tool Suite:

> | Error 2015-06-12 18:19:18,357 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Unsuccessful: alter table meta_data_master_template add index FK6FD57D1CFA081AA2 (protocol_id), add constraint FK6FD57D1CFA081AA2 foreign key (protocol_id) references protocol (protocol_id)
>
> | Error 2015-06-12 18:19:18,357 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`datumrite`.`#sql-1204_4`, CONSTRAINT `FK6FD57D1CFA081AA2` FOREIGN KEY (`protocol_id`) REFERENCES `protocol` (`protocol_id`))
>
> | Error 2015-06-12 18:19:21,887 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Error creating bean with name 'org.grails.activiti.springsecurity.SetAuthenticatedUserIdFilters': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngine': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/ibatis/session/SqlSessionFactory;
>
> Message: Error creating bean with name 'org.grails.activiti.springsecurity.SetAuthenticatedUserIdFilters': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngine': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/ibatis/session/SqlSessionFactory;
>
> Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngine': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/ibatis/session/SqlSessionFactory;

Comment: What does STS have to do with this? Does it work correctly when running from the commandline?

Comment: I am getting this when running in commandline : 

| Error 2015-06-15 15:00:39,479 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR core.StandardConte
xt  - Error listenerStart

| Error 2015-06-15 15:00:39,494 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR core.StandardConte
xt  - Context [/clindata] startup failed due to previous errors
2015-06-15 15:00:39,557 [main] INFO  http11.Http11Protocol  - Starting ProtocolH
andler ["http-bio-8080"]

| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/clindata
| Application loaded in interactive mode. Type 'exit' to shutdown.
| Enter a script name to run. Use TAB for completion:
grails>

Comment: possible duplicate of [grails - error when running the application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800048/grails-error-when-running-the-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the message suggests, drop the `CONSTRAINT FK6FD57D1CFA081AA2` from your DB and try again. Alternatively you can remove `dbCreate = "update"` from your DataSource

Comment: Yes! It worked.. But have one more error left.
| Error 2015-06-15 10:49:58,545 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Error creating bean with name 'org.grails.activiti.springsecurity.SetAuthenticatedUserIdFilters': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

Comment: I am getting the last 2 errors mentioned 

Message: Error creating bean with name & Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngine': Initialization of bean failed;

Comment: open another question for that and post the stacktrace there

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30845324/error-trying-to-execute-grails-application-in-sts